# Protoc regen commands requires different proto imports for generating java and dart files?

Tags: java, dart, backend, protocol-buffers

I have a directory that looks like this:

- protos

  - user

    - user_service.proto
    - user_context.proto
    - user.proto

The user_service.proto imports my user_context.proto and user.proto.

---

user_service.proto:

```
package com.project.protos.user;

import "protos/user/user.proto";
import "protos/user/user_context.proto";

service UserService {
    rpc GetUser(UserContext) returns (User);
}
```

---

user_context.proto:

```
package com.project.protos.user;

message UserContext {
    string token = 1;
}
```

With the imports "**protos**/user/user.proto", I can generate my java files using the following command:
`protoc --java_out=services/src/main/java protos\user\user_service.proto` 
But when I try to generate the dart files, I get the following errors

```
protoc --dart_out=grpc:project/lib/protos -Iprotos protos/user/user_service.proto

user/user.proto: File not found.
user/user_context.proto: File not found.
protos/user/user_service.proto:10:1: Import "user/user.proto" was not found or had errors.
protos/user/user_service.proto:11:1: Import "user/user_context.proto" was not found or had errors.
protos/user/user_service.proto:20:3: "UserContext" is not defined.
protos/user/user_service.proto:21:3: "User" is not defined.
protos/user/user_service.proto:14:15: "UserContext" is not defined.
protos/user/user_service.proto:14:37: "User" is not defined.
protos/user/user_service.proto:16:40: "User" is not defined.
```

---

To get around this, I have been **SPECIFICALLY** changing my imports in to be import "user/user.proto" (omitting the top protos/ directory) which makes my dart files generate but causes issues generating my java files.

Changing the imports for when I generate my java and dart files sounds really inefficient and sounds like I am doing something wrong. Can anyone see if I am missing anything or if there are any other things I could try?

Comment: Imports must be relative to include directory. In your case this means that for all languages you should use "protoc --{java|dart|...}_out=path/to/dir -I. protos/user/user_service.proto". Alternatively, you can remove "proto" from all your imports ("import user/user.proto") and use "protoc --{java|dart|...}_out=path/to/dir -Iprotos protos/user/user_service.proto".

Comment: @gudok your comment is the answer; for posterity, please consider posting it as the answer.